# Cannot debug Provider-Hosted Add-In: VS2017 hangs opening Chrome (resolved)

Tags: visual-studio, provider-hosted-app, debugging

### Update:

**Resolved (hope so).** Maybe this is a bug and upgrade VS2017 to to **15.7.6** helps. I close my Chrome every time before f5

--

Every [How-to](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/main/docs/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins.md) for beginners in the net say "Hit F5 and voila!" - but my VS2017 hangs at this step. The only thing I can do - is close to Visual Studio.

[image]

Sometimes it works: I successfully deployed my provider hosted app twice today:

- Disabled all chrome extensions and closed chrome
- Tried to enable/disable Javascript Debugging in VS settings:

[image]
<sub>(source: [preview.ibb.co](https://preview.ibb.co/d1fRdz/2.png))</sub>

- Played with firewall
- Tried to stop/start IIS sites
- Tried to set up my Add-in as "Startup project" in VS project settings..

But sometimes it works and sometimes not, I cannot find dependency..
Think it works if I restart pc, close all tabs in Chrome, close chrome, open VS first time, and hit f5 (not sure). But if I press Shift+f5 and then try debug again - it hangs

How do You debug Provider-Hosted Add-ins?....